# Struts2: Get the Url the User came from

Tags: java, struts2

How can i get the URL from which the user came to my Struts2 Action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

You can also create a hidden field in the form and then use a if statement to check and route accordingly.

I'd recommend you use the hidden field. While it is certainly more of a hassle it is also more reliable.
The referer field can be stripped from the HTTP header by a proxy. In fact the browser isn't required to send the referer field in the header at all.

See a good discussion [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t369762-getting-a-referring-url.html).
The above explanation is an extract from that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer):

```
String url = request.getHeader("referer");
```

However you need to be cautious as this is an optional value passed by the browser.  In other words, not all clients will pass it to you.

A safer option is to pass the calling page as a hidden input value.